# Why does mprobe fail when checking string literals?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, heap-memory

In an effort to ensure a data structure that I implemented is functionally sound, I wrote a test file utilizing `mcheck` to be certain that I am working within the bounds of allocated memory. However when trying to use `mprobe()` on a string literal (and calling `mcheck(NULL)` at the beginning), the program always aborts with `MCHECK_HEAD`.

I tried this with the smallest program I can conceive:

```
#include <mcheck.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    mcheck(NULL);
    mprobe("test");

    exit(0);

}
```

The result is the following:

```sh
$ gcc test.c -lmcheck
$ ./a.out
memory clobbered before allocated block
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So it seems that mcheck fails whenever it encounters a string literal, thinking that preceding memory has been modified. Why? Is it because the string isn't explicitly `malloc`ed?

Comment: "allocated memory" refers to memory allocated by `malloc` family functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> enum mcheck_status mprobe(void *ptr);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The `mprobe()`  function performs a consistency check on the block of allocated memory pointed to by `ptr`.

A string literal is not a pointer to allocated memory. The C standard very strictly defines *allocated storage* as that which is allocated with `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and the like. POSIX extends the list e.g. with `strdup`. A string literal, on the other hand, is a non-modifiable **array** of characters with static storage duration, though it does not have a `const` element type which is why you didn't get a warning. Try:

```
char *foo = "test";
const char *bar = "test";
mprobe(foo);
mprobe(bar);
```

and the compiler [reports a constraint violation](https://godbolt.org/z/x1wEe-) compiling the latter call:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:12:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'mprobe' discards 'const' qualifier
from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   12 |     mprobe(bar);
      |            ^~~
In file included from <source>:1:
/usr/include/mcheck.h:53:41: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of
type 'const char *'
   53 | extern enum mcheck_status mprobe (void *__ptr) __THROW;
      |                                   ~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Comment: I see. So are all constant pointers disqualified from functionally being considered 'allocated memory'?

Comment: @JSONBrody It’s not a “block of allocated memory”, string literals live together in a memory segment, they aren’t allocated separately. Documentation also states the memory must have been allocated with malloc or realloc.